# Do POST in java with json-simple

Tags: java, json, rest, post, server

I have a `REST` service and i want do a `POST` query with `JSON`, but it is not working.

Below is the example of my other query which works right :

```
@GET
@Path("/getByIdJSON/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person getPersonByIdJSON(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return personDao.getById(id);
}
```

and the above query give me the below response from server :

```
{"person":{"id":11,"fullName":"Maria","age":19,"city":"Tver","gender":"female"}}
```

This is DAO for : `getPersonByIdJSON`

```
    public Person getById(int id) {
    Person person = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        person = (Person) session.createQuery("from Person p where p.id = :ID").setParameter("ID", id).uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return person;
}
```

For `POST` I do this:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveNewPerson(JSONObject person) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    obj.put("fullName",new String());
    obj.put("age",new String());
    obj.put("city",new String());
    obj.put("gender",new String());

    person.put("person", obj);
    if (!personDao.savePerson(person)) {
        return "Person create success   id=";

    }
    else {
        return "error, check information for new person";
    }
}
```

and DAO:

```
 public boolean savePerson(JSONObject person) {
    Session session = null;
    boolean hasErrors = false;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(person);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        hasErrors = true;

    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return hasErrors;
}
```

Now, To add new person, I sent to server `POST query` (***via RestEasy***) and in the Body i write this:

```
{"person":{"fullName":"newperson","age":19,"city":"exampleCity","gender":"female"}}
```

But it does not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveNewPerson(Person person){
//...
}
```

[Please see section 5 on this page.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

Comment: very thanks, if i am use Java, Maven, TomCat, MySql, Hibernate, how to make a post without jersey

Comment: You need a JAX-RS (REST) implementation anyway because your code wants to use the REST API. Tomcat does not have a built in REST implementation so you have to deploy one. Jersey is a REST implementation (the default one) so it is a good candidate to be deployed under Tomcat. You can check this page how to deploy the Jersey in your war: http://laszlo.gazsi.net/restful-web-service-example-on-tomcat-using-jersey/